# Join this Community bug on Area51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, authentication

When I clicked on the "Join This Community" banner on an area 51 question, I was redirected to the following page:

https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/join?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fdiscuss.area51.stackexchange.com%2fquestions%2f18036%2fswagoverflow-clothing

[image: Page Not Found]

Comment: What's a community bug, and why do I want to join it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! I'm pushing a fix and it will go live in the next build.

As a bonus, I'm also removing the "sign up" link from Area 51 Discuss since that also doesn't exist on Area 51 quite in the same way as it does on core Q&A sites.

Comment: Hi Adam, maybe I have a similar issue. I'm logged in SE, but I don't see a "join this community" button in Mathoverflow. Only "sign up" and "log in". Is this normal?

Comment: @Aubrey Depends. :) If you haven't explicitly logged in in a while (i.e. if you've logged in once a few months ago and never since), your session may pre-date how we track your account across the network. Failing that, if you're using a browser with third-party cookies disabled (e.g. Safari), we also can't do the same tracking, so you'd see sign up/log in instead of join. The good news, if you "log in" and use the same credentials as you normally do, your profile will get linked up to the right account regardless.